# Handle click outside element in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am looking to create a custom lookup component using Lightning Web Components. I want to be able to detect when the user is clicking outside of the element so that I can close the dialog and/or clear the text if nothing is selected. I can't seem to use standard Javascript since `template.contains(e.target)` and DOM traversal doesn't seem to detect whether the clicked element is inside of the component or not. Here is a sample of what I have attempted.

1. DOM traversal

```
let parent = this.template.querySelector('.slds-form-element__row');//parent element
let targetElement = e.target; // clicked element

do {
  if (targetElement == parent) {
    window.console.log('clicked inside');
    return;
  }
  // Go up the DOM
  targetElement = targetElement.parentNode;
} while (targetElement);

window.console.log('clicked outside');
```

2. template.contains(e.target)

```
if (this.template.querySelector('.slds-form-element__row').contains(e.target)) {
  window.console.log('clicked inside');
} else {
  window.console.log('clicked outside');
}
```

In both of these cases, `clicked outside` is the only thing I will see since `e.target` doesn't seem to exist within the DOM element, but I do know my click event (which I've attached to `document`) is firing since I do see the console.log statement in my developer console.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't navigate outside your own template. That's one of the security features of LWC's shadow DOM. Instead, create a transparent, fixed div that covers the entire screen area, then react to that, instead:

```
<template>
  <div class="backdrop" onclick={closeModal}></div>
  <div class="content">... your content here ...</div>
</template>
```

---

```
.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.content {
  z-index: 1000;
  /* anything else you need here */
}
```

For a complete example, look at Lightning Strike's [Lookup component](https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components/tree/master/aura/strike_lookup) (written in Aura, but still applicable).

Comment: Instead of doing that he should detect a click outside. He can create a reusable module to do something like suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028037/627569

Comment: @citizenconn That's essentially what they're trying to do, but you can't access the DOM outside your component in LWC. This is because of a feature known as the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_dom). Of course, you could encapsulate the backdrop as a custom component of itself, but that would only save a couple of lines of code.

Comment: To clarify, this would definitely work, but I think looking back at my question it wasn't entirely clear. I am not trying to access anything outside of my component. `.slds-form-element__row` exists within my template, but I am thinking that maybe the locker service wrapper around elements is what is causing my comparison checks to fail, since it is a proxy instead of the element itself. I will review the Strike component and hopefully that will give me some ideas. Thanks!

Comment: That Strike component gave me a great idea. I left everything the way I had it, but added `event.stopPropagation()` to all of my click events within my component to prevent the click from bubbling up and left the `window.addEventListener()` really simple to just close the popup if a click event ever gets that far, which solved my issues with comparison checks. Probably should have thought of that first, but thanks either way!

Comment: @BiscuitKnees Ah, I presumed window.addEventListener directly was prohibited. I guess I should have read the code more closely. If you want, you can add your own answer (we totally encourage that) so others can benefit.

Comment: @sfdcfox yes but they're trying to do it from within the component and reach out instead of outside and using the component APIs.

Comment: This is genius, love the solution! Thanks @sfdcfox!

Comment: @sfdcfox, this saved me again!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is graceful! Thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks a lot. It is really working.

Answer (score 12):

Although I wasn't able to solve my above problem exactly as I posted it, I was able to solve it with a different approach.

I believe the issue I was having was locker service related. This is just a theory, but I believe since `e.target` in my scenario is a proxy, it can't be used to compare against other nodes within my DOM, even if they are within the same component.

I was able to work around this issue by restructuring my code a little bit so that I am not relying on DOM node comparison. Here is an example of the final code.

```
onNodeClick = () => {
  this._isOpen = true;

  //Timeout is to prevent the click from continuing and closing the element right away.
  //Just this slight delay of 0 is enough to stop propagation
  window.setTimeout(() => window.addEventListener('click', this.handleClose), 0);
}

handleClose = () => {
  this._isOpen = false;
  window.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClose);
}
```

Comment: Also, important to note that any other click events that should happen within the element would also need to use `e.stopPropagation()` in order to stop the event from bubbling up further unless you want that click to close the popup.

Comment: This is a nice trick. I didn't realize with locker on we can add window events safely (see current api spec here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer)

Comment: Great technique! I was able to do away with the setTimeout call also, by calling event.stopImmediatePropagation(). Also note... the callback must be either an arrow function or bound to 'this'... I missed that in the code above and spend half and hour or so sorting it out.

Comment: Hi, can you share your LWC code for this bit of functionality to close dropdown on outside click but maintain state if clicked inside options?

Answer (score 1):

Another tweak I found it working shown below. "onmouseleve" gets called when mouse is taken out of the component where it's mentioned.

```
 <div onmouseleave={function}> 
    <Your content here>

 </div>
```

Comment: Is the `onmouseleave` on lookup component? Can you add bit more detail in your code(html and js).